# Magento 1.7 Offline Maintenance Extension

Tags: magento-1.7

In Magento how to keep store offline or maintenance mode from admin side.
Admin must able to surf the magento store, but restricted to other users.
Any plugin or script or how to do it from admin login.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-maintenance.html
provides exactly what you are looking for and more

Answer (score 0):

Check out this http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/all4coding-offline-maintenance-page.html it provide exactly what you are looking for. compatible with magento 1.4 - 1.8